# Ford focus 2012 low beam turn off while car turned on

Tags: ford, focus

hello thanks for trying to help me..
The issue i have is that i just installed an Hid kit for a ford focus 2012 and while the car is off ignition the low beam work they turn on, but as soon as i turn on the car the low beams turn off

Comment: Some hids have a low voltage restart problem - try starting the engine **then** turning on the low beam. Let us know...

Comment: I tried that and it still didnt work :/

Comment: With oem bulbs they did work, they told me i needed some resistors, but they arent flashing

Comment: And the other solution is they told me i needed a canceller cable

Comment: If you guys want i could post a video

Answer (score 0):

ok this is usuallly associated with an earth or ground[fault . ie the earth strap from body of car to engine is loose corroded or missing .. so make sure there is a good strong copper wire connecting the body of the motor to the engiee . just find a bolt on the engine that you can put the earth wire on to and another point on the body of the vehicle where you can bond the two tightly together.. try this and come back and tell us if its a fix.

Comment: I checked all the ground and it didnt work, i put the oem bulbs and they did work, but not with the hid

Answer (score 0):

i have this same problem with my family car,
the culprit is wrong connection on my relay.

relay for car usually have 2 out

- 1. NC (normally Closed) meaning without input voltage in relay this output still contact (will have output voltage)
- 2. NO (normally open) meaning in normal condition (without input) is no output.

you are probably connecting the NC connection to your low beam and the input from relay is jumped from your battery (ACC)? please check it again if you have right connection between your switch lamp - relay - relay (probably you have original relay below your dashboard, please double check)